# Removing gap between last two words in a string in R

Tags: r, string, gsub

I am trying to remove the gap between the last two words in dataframe that contains multiple strings. I have tried using `gsub` but my attempt of `gsub("(\\s){1}$","",df1$V1)` seems quite wrong! `df1` is my dataset and `df2` is the result I am after.

```
df1 <- data.frame(V1=c("Apple Pear Orange, AAA 111", "Grapes Banana Pear . BBB 222", "Orange Kiwi Melon , CCC 333", "Apple DDD 444", "Kiwi Melon Orange CCC 333", "Apple Pear Orange, AAA 111", "Tomato Cucumber EEE 222", "Seagull Pigeon ZZZ 111" ), stringsAsFactors = F)

df2 <- data.frame(V1=c("Apple Pear Orange, AAA111", "Grapes Banana Pear . BBB222", "Orange Kiwi Melon , CCC333", "Apple DDD444", "Kiwi Melon Orange CCC333", "Apple Pear Orange, AAA111", "Tomato Cucumber EEE222", "Seagull Pigeon ZZZ111" ), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or even this:

```
gsub("(.*)\\s","\\1",df1$V1)
```

Comment: This works for all the strings in my real dataset. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use capture groups:

```
sub("(.*)\\s+([^\\s]+)$", "\\1\\2", df1$V1)
#[1] "Apple Pear Orange, AAA111"   "Grapes Banana Pear . BBB222" "Orange Kiwi Melon , CCC333"  "Apple DDD444"               
#[5] "Kiwi Melon Orange CCC333"    "Apple Pear Orange, AAA111"   "Tomato Cucumber EEE222"      "Seagull Pigeon ZZZ111"
```

This captures as first group any number of characters, then 1+ spaces and as second group 1+ characters that are not spaces until the end of the string. It then only extracts the two capture groups without the spaces in between.

Comment: Could you use the `\\w+` for words instead? `gsub("(\\w+) (\\w+$)", "\\1\\2" ,df1$V1)`? Just a thought...

Comment: @MikeH., sure but why don't you propose this as a seprate answer?

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure why, but your syntax does not work for all of the strings in my actual dataset when the answers by hhh and Mike H. do.

Answer (score 1):

Going off Docendo's answer, you could use `\\w+` to match words of any length:

```
gsub("(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+$)", "\\1\\2" ,df1$V1)

#[1] "Apple Pear Orange, AAA111"   "Grapes Banana Pear . BBB222" "Orange Kiwi Melon , CCC333" 
#[4] "Apple DDD444"                "Kiwi Melon Orange CCC333"    "Apple Pear Orange, AAA111"  
#[7] "Tomato Cucumber EEE222"      "Seagull Pigeon ZZZ111"
```

Then you can use the same idea with the capture groups.

Comment: Thanks. This does exactly what I was after as well, but as hhh answered first I have accepted their solution as the answer.